# assigning permissions via CSOM C#

Tags: development, office-365, csom, 2016

I am trying to assign permissions to document library via C# CSOM

Below is the code that I am using

```
public string AssignPermission(ClientContext ctx, string[] accountName, string folderUrl,RoleType role) {
            try
            {
                foreach (string userid in accountName)
                {
                    if (userid.Length > 0) { 
                        User user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(userid);
                        Folder folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
                        var roleDefinition = ctx.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(role);  //get Reader role
                        var roleBindings = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(ctx) { roleDefinition };
                        folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);  //set folder unique permissions
                        folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleBindings);
                        folder.Update();
                    }
                }
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                return "Permission Assigned";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

The code usage is like below

```
AssignPermission(context, userids, folderUrl, RoleType.Reader);
```

The problem I am facing is, even if I give `RoleType.Reader`, it is assigning only full control permission for the user

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example which creates a folder in a library, breaks the permissions and assigns Contributor role to the user. You can modify it per your needs.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://aissp2013:90"))
{
  Site site = clientContext.Site;                
  Web web = clientContext.Web;
  List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
  Folder newFolder = list.RootFolder.Folders.Add("F4");
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();    
  newFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);
  var role = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
  role.Add(web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Contributor));
  User user = web.EnsureUser("contoso\\adamb");
  newFolder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(user, role);
  newFolder.Update();
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();          
}
```

Comment: tried it same problem!